# \NeedsTeXFormat for LuaLaTeX or LaTeX2e

Tags: package-writing

I work on some "homemade" packages that work with LaTeX2e and eventually with LuaLaTeX for some optional features.

What is the standard way to use `\NeedsTeXFormat` in that kind of situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\NeedsTeXFormat` doesn't care about the engine at all, so it doesn't make a difference if your package can be used with LuaLaTeX or not. Just write

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
```

(of course you can add a date if necessary)

If you actually *require* LuaLaTeX (or another engine), then you have to add a test for that separately. You can use e.g. `iftex` for that:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{...}...

...

\RequirePackage{iftex}
\RequireLuaTeX
```